# Can not access file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, centos

I'm using Rails in centOS.

rake db:migrate is not run.

Is there a way to fix?
Should I rebuild?

```
[root@localhost db]# ll
ls: cannot access development.sqlite3: Permission denied
total 125
-?????????? ? ?    ?         ?            ? development.sqlite3
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   8192 Jun 20 16:44 migrate
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 102400 Jun 25 10:58 production.sqlite3
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  14850 Jun 25 11:00 schema.rb
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root   1341 Jun 25 20:10 seeds.rb
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      0 Jun 25 20:16 test.sqlite3
[root@localhost db]# rm development.sqlite3 
rm: cannot remove `development.sqlite3': Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

May be permission issue
try using super user

```
sudo rake db:migrate
```

or give permission to folder using

```
chmod -r 777 folder_name
```